# Upgrade to .Net 4.7.2 causing SharePoint Add-in error

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, csom, .net-4.7.2

We have SharePoint Addin (webhosted) where it was working fine until we upgraded .Net Framework to 4.7.2 for On-Prem environments. After upgrading application Framework to 4.7.2(from 4.6.2) client context creation is failing with error

> Could not get algorithm from X509AsymmetricSecurityKey

The complete error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException HResult=0x80131509 Message=Could not get algorithm from X509AsymmetricSecurityKey Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions
>
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(X509AsymmetricSecurityKey x509Key)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.SignatureProvider.Create(SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.Sign(String signingInput, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.WriteTokenAsString(SecurityToken token)

I'm trying with this configuration but that doesn't help much:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" requestValidationMode="4.5" executionTimeout="2400"/>
</system.web>
```

Any help here very much appreciated.

Ravi Nalla